# How to configure the Project ( depends on maven/web.xml/servlet APi) AJAX call not to include the Project name in it?

Tags: java, jquery, tomcat, servlets, maven-2

I am trying to deploy my WAR in TOMCAT server, and i am using MAVEN 2. My Project name is 
"**Jira-Synchronization**". My project is a simple Ajax call and returns result to display to the user. I have only one page( that's the scope of my project). This is how i made the Ajax call and web.xml

```
$.getJSON('/Jira-Synchronization/jirarequest','OK', function(jiraData) 


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>Jira-Synchronization</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>JiraSyncServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>JiraSyncServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>JiraSyncServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/jirarequest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

if you notice the ajax call is taking the Project name( first i felt weired why it is doing that and to move on with the project i just kept it that way) and every thing worked fine inside eclipse running tomcat(This is the URL i used when running from eclipse `http://localhost:8080/Jira-Synchronization/index.html`).

When i tried to build it using maven and deploy in tomcat(out side of eclipse) the War is made using this name "**Jira-Synchronization-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT**. My URL has changed to`http://localhost:8080/Jira-Synchronization-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/index.html` and now my Ajax call which have my project name in it is also need to be changed. this is how my pom.xml looks like

[image]

How should i configure my web.xml or pom.xml so that the ajax request excludes the project name to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me is in the Pom.xml i added this `<finalName>Jira-Synchronization</finalName>` under the `<build>` tag and that was able to output the WAR with the desired name as i like